# How do I restart iptables in Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, iptables

I am trying to block port 111, I did the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 111 -j DROP
```

then I did `rpcinfo -p {IP of Debian 8.5 server}` from a different server, but, port 111 is still open.

> ```
> program vers proto   port  service
> 100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
> 100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
> 100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
> 100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
> 100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
> 100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
> 100024    1   udp  57185  status
> 100024    1   tcp  58632  status
> ```

I restart the Debian 8.5 server machine, but still no luck. How do I 'restart' iptables in a Debian 8.5 machine?

---

```
iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2255 packets, 870K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:111

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2367 packets, 445K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Maybe the servers talk using IPv6.  Try adding the same rule using `ip6tables`.

Comment: As for restarting: iptables is build into the kernel, so there's no way to restart it independently.  There are, however, methods to reset the rules.  Be careful though, you wouldn't be the first to lock yourself out of a server.  Trust me, I should know ;)

Comment: @tarleb I was afraid of that. And also added the same rule in the `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` as in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`, rebooting now , and hoping fpor the best...

Comment: @tarleb No luck? :/

Comment: What does `iptables -nvL --line-numbers` give you?

Comment: @tarleb I do see a line about port 111: `1        0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:111` - But rpcinfo gives me the same information still as mentioned in my question

Comment: Please edit your question with the full `iptables -nvL --line-numbers` output (edit IP address if you're paranoid).  It's possible you may have an `ACCEPT` rule higher in the list.

Comment: @StephenHarris Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpcinfo` will try both `tcp` and `udp` connections to talk to the portmapper.  Indeed in a quick test I did, `tcp` was attempted before `udp`.

You need to block both protocols in order to prevent remote access to it.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 111 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 111 -j DROP
```

Many RPC services listen on both protocols; you can see this in your `rpcinfo` output.

Comment: The odd thing is that in the OP's output, it seems that TCP *and* UDP are *both* available.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - no, `rpcinfo` just reports on what the portmapper knows about, not what is reachable.  As long as `rpcinfo` can reach the portmapper via TCP then it'll report on all protocols and all registered services.  It doesn't do an active probe.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work! `rpcinfo -p` is not able to read any information.

Comment: @StephenHarris Huh. My mistake, then. It's been well over a decade since I last touched the rpc\* family of tools.